# .htaccess rewrite rule for adding a segment to a url

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with setting up the .htaccess file for redirecting old urls to new ones. The difference is the new 'categories' segment. Note that the website has multiple languages. Any help or tips are much appreciated!

old url:

```
http://www.website.com/en/products/142/accessories-hoses/490/sg-01-manhole-grid-deflection
```

new url:

```
http://www.website.com/en/products/categories/142/accessories-hoses/490/sg-01-manhole-grid-deflection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as **top rule** in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en/products)/(\d+/.+)$ /$1/categories/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```